# Using Web Deploy tool for IIS - works with administrator account but not IIS or Windows user account

Tags: visual-studio, iis-7, permissions, http-status-code-401, webdeploy

I am struggling with the massive beast that seems to be WMSvc - Web Management service for IIS.

I am trying to deploy web sites from Visual Studio which is killing me. Actually it's killing everyone except me on my team, but since I am designated web server manager right now I'm the one thats feeling the hurt.

It works when I deploy using my Admin windows account, which atleast means I should be on my way, but it doesn't work with another account that isn't admin or an IIS manager account.

Let me show you what I've done:

1. Installed WMSvc.
2. Seemingly configured it. Under MYSERVER/Management Service I the settings are:

   ```
   Enable Remote Connections
   Windows credentials or IIS Manager credentials
   Access for unspecified clients - allow.
   ```
3. Added a user MYUSER as IIS Manager account. Also added a windows account MYSERVER\MYUSER
4. Added those users under MYSERVER/My web site/IIS Manager Permissions.
5. Sacrificed a goat.
6. Added rules under MYSERVER/Management Service Delegation

   ```
   Deploy Applications with Content - and added user *
   Set Permissions - and added user *
   ```

After all this, it worked from my Windows admin account, but not from the other accounts. Visual Studio reported 401 unauthorized. In the article I followed there was the below citation under Troubleshooting:

> User receives 401 unauthorized error
>   while trying to connect to a Web site.
>   o Cause(s): This error comes from
>   WMSVC and is usually an error with
>   username/password, or because the user
>   does not have access to the Web site.
>   o Resolution(s): Verify the
>   username/password and that the user
>   has access to the Web site.

But to be honest, I have no idea what I've done wrong by now. Any ideas?

Thanks for any answers.

Comment: LOL....+1 for step 5: *Sacrificed a goat.*

Answer (score 0):

Did you grant file system privileges to the `Local Service` account?  That is the account that the WMSvc runs as, so it needs access to the file system to do it's job.

If you right click on the site in IIS there should be a context menu option for "Edit Persmissions...".  That will take you directly to the permissions section of the folder properties for the web site directory.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the (albeit a bit late) answer! I DID figure this out, even though it wasn't exactly obvious for me (at the time). The problem was that I connected through htt**p**://server/ instead of http**s**://server/ (don't remember the ports). This was a problem because the first one connected to a service that was separate from IIS, and only accepted windows accounts. HTTPS connects to the IIS web management service.