# Why is Web Deploy saying Administrator is not an admin?

Tags: webdeploy, iis-8.5, webdeploy-3.5

I have a Server 2012 R2 machine on a domain to which I would like to use Web Deploy to deploy a web site.  This works fine when I use my domain credentials.

Web Deploy fails with `ERROR_USER_NOT_ADMIN` when I use either the **Administrator** account, or a new account in the **Administrators** group.

```
Error Code: ERROR_USER_NOT_ADMIN
More Information: Connected to '192.168.76.109' using the Web Deployment Agent Service, but could not authorize. Make sure you are an administrator on '192.168.76.109'.  Learn more at: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=221672#ERROR_USER_NOT_ADMIN.
Error: The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.
```

I have tried using the special [**MSDepSvcUsers** group](http://www.iis.net/learn/publish/troubleshooting-web-deploy/web-deploy-error-codes#ERROR_USER_NOT_ADMIN), installing all sorts of [remote management tools](http://forums.iis.net/post/1960329.aspx) for IIS 8.5, [delegating permissions](http://www.iis.net/learn/publish/using-web-deploy/configure-the-web-deployment-handler), and [reinstalling Web Deploy](http://althoffchronicles.blogspot.com/2013/05/msdeployagentservice-401.html) after installing the remote management features.  Because I am a vegetarian, I have not yet tried [sacrificing a goat](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5444878/222481).

Why can't I use a local account to deploy my web site?